# How do I incorporate two home functions in flutter main.dart

Tags: flutter

I am looking to have an app with sidebar navigation and also authenticate user on starting the app. The sidebar function ensures the side navigation on every page of the application using the navigation states and the new rootpage ensures that the users get authenticated in order to use the applications. The two require to use a home: function and one cannot have the two in the main.dart file. Any ideas i can incorporate both of them

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'services/authentication.dart'; //authentication module
import 'sidebar/sidebar_layout.dart'; sidebar navigation
import 'pages/root_page.dart'; //page that looks if user has an id 

void main() => runApp(MyApp());


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp( 
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'M-Afya',
      theme: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        primaryColor: Colors.white,

      ),

       home: new RootPage(auth: new Auth()) //ensures one must be authenticated to use the application
      home: SideBarLayout() //sidebar navigation 

    );

  }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It's quite difficult to understand what you want to do based on your description and code. Try to clarify your issue.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a video that will help you for switches between lgoin and home page + state initialization and you can add your sidebar accordingly. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pl1rKBnmDkU